# Visa for Spain: how to fill in the form EX-09?

Tags: visa, spain

I am applying for a Visa for Spain (for my PhD).

One of the forms I need to present is the [EX-09](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Documents/Formulario%20EX-09.pdf). I asked for help on how to properly fill it in at the Embassy in my country but they do not provide this sort of assistance.

At the bottom of the first page there are two fields: “DIRIGIDA A” and “PROVINCIA”. What should I write there (I’ll present these documents to the General Consulate in Rome, not directly to a public office in Spain)? Some websites provide unofficial guidelines on how to fill in this sort of forms but they usually assume you are already in Spain.

Comment: Your form may be outdated (1999) and contains invalid internet addresses. Here a link to the Spanish Immigration Office page with all forms: [IMMIGRATION PORTAL. General models](https://extranjeros.inclusion.gob.es/es/ModelosSolicitudes/Mod_solicitudes2/index.html), without any non-spanish versions. The form Ex-09 looks different than the London consulate version, but seems to ask the same information.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Oh, thank you very much for the information!